# hide some numbers with star in phone number UIlabel using for otp verification swift 4 app

Tags: swift

i am making an app in swift 4 and i want the enetered number label text to show something like this when otp is sent

" otp is sent to +91******21 "

here is the thing I found now I don't own what logic should be applied here to post string like that

```
var mobileNumer = "+91987654321"
let intLetters = mobileNumer.prefix(3)
let endLetters = mobileNumer.suffix(2)
```

i want this tpe of number to be shown on the label after enytering the mobile number , it should show frist two numbers then start and hen show last two numbers

Comment: `mobileNumer.prefix(3) + repeatElement("•", count: 6) + mobileNumer.suffix(2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
var mobileNumer = "+91987654321"
let intLetters = mobileNumer.prefix(3)
let endLetters = mobileNumer.suffix(2)

let newString = intLetters + "*******" + endLetters   //"+91*******21"
```

Or if you want to be safe:

```
var mobileNumer = "+91987654321"

guard mobileNumer.count > 5 else {
    fatalError("The phone number is not complete")
}

let intLetters = mobileNumer.prefix(3)
let endLetters = mobileNumer.suffix(2)

let stars = String(repeating: "*", count: mobileNumer.count - 5)

let result = intLetters + stars + endLetters
```

Or if you'd prefer to replace a subrange:

```
var mobileNumer = "+91987654321"

guard mobileNumer.count > 5 else {
    fatalError("The phone number is not complete")
}

let startingIndex = mobileNumer.index(mobileNumer.startIndex, offsetBy: 3)
let endingIndex = mobileNumer.index(mobileNumer.endIndex, offsetBy: -2)
let stars = String(repeating: "*", count: mobileNumer.count - 5)
let result = mobileNumer.replacingCharacters(in: startingIndex..<endingIndex,
        with: stars)
```

Or

If you'd like to mutate `mobileNumer`:

```
mobileNumer.replaceSubrange(startingIndex..<endingIndex, with: stars)
print(mobileNumer) //"+91*******21"
```

Comment: I want dynamic one sir, I have tried this one but its not suitable

Comment: @RahulSharma What do you mean by dynamic? I did update my answer

Comment: thanx sir it looks god. can I get the same example using "stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString" method if possible ?

Comment: @RahulSharma I used `replacingCharacters` instead in the updated answer

Comment: @RahulSharma I understand that you are new here. But if this (or any other) answer has helped you in achieving what you wanted to achieve please accept the answer by clicking on the tick mark. Its a way of saying thank you to others for taking out their time and helping you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this function.

```
func starifyNumber(number: String) -> String {
        let intLetters = number.prefix(3)
        let endLetters = number.suffix(2)
        let numberOfStars = number.count - (intLetters.count + endLetters.count)
        var starString = ""
        for _ in 1...numberOfStars {
            starString += "*"
        }
        let finalNumberToShow: String = intLetters + starString + endLetters
        return finalNumberToShow
    }
```

To call it

```
let mobileNumer = starifyNumber(number: "+91987654321")
print(mobileNumer) \\+91*******21
```

Comment: `func starifyNumber(number: String) -> Substring {
    return number.prefix(3) + repeatElement("•", count: 6) + number.suffix(2)
}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Interesting!! Looks nice and sleek. But no matter how long or short the number is. Going by your logic it would always show 6 *s. Think he wants dynamic and by dynamic he wants to preserve the length of the number provided.

Comment: Op it is not implementing a text field it is a string

Comment: Agree to that. But its a mobile number in question. Which we can safely assume  to be provided by the user. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes but OP wants to mask the users phone number and even if there is less it will show only bullets anyway. The phone number probably comes from a json response from the server

Comment: Hmmm... Fair enough!!